# How to download file from bytes by using web api and angular

Tags: c#, .net, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I have used below code to download file. I have successfully assigned bytearray in web api.

```
    byte[] bytes = llResponse.FileContent;
    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes)
```

But finally i am getting below response my browser console

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36098:51) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9462:31) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:99246:33) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9461:60) at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9239:47) at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9536:34) at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10674:14) at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10711:21)
message: "Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0
```

Complete code i have used is as below

**angular**

```
 this.appService.DownloadFile(this.filter).subscribe((data) => {  
                
                
                importedSaveAs(data, this.filter.FileName)  

            })



public DownloadFile(obj:liveLinkFilter): Observable<any> {
        var url = this.baseApiUrl + 'RadioLink/DownloadFile';
        var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        return this.httpService.post(url, obj, { headers: reqHeader, withCredentials: true });
    }
```

**Web Api code**

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("DownloadFile")]
        public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFile(LiveLinkDocumentBO obj)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            LLAccessResponse llResponse;

            //GetFileType(lvlnkBo.FileName);
            LLService llservice = new LLService();
            
            llResponse = llservice.FetchDocument(Convert.ToInt32(obj.FileId), obj.LLUserName, obj.FileName);
            //Read the File into a Byte Array.  
            byte[] bytes = llResponse.FileContent;
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
            //Set the Response Content Length.  
            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = bytes.LongLength;
            //Set the Content Disposition Header Value and FileName.  
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = obj.FileName;
            //Set the File Content Type.  
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(obj.FileName));
            return response;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular's HttpClient assumes that the respose is JSON by default. If the response from your API is a text string, set the `responseType` property of the HTTP request options (the third argument to `httpService.post`) to `"text"`. If the response is binary data, set the response type to `"arraybuffer"` or `"blob"`.